# How can I generate an ssl/cert.pem file?

Tags: http, ssl, terminal, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

New to this, I'm attempting to create a locally-trusted development certificate via mkcert. When I run the following command in terminal:

```
mkcert -key-file ssl/key.pem -cert-file ssl/cert.pem localhost.my-domain.com localhost
```

It yields the following error message:

> ERROR: failed to save certificate: open ssl/cert.pem: no such file or directory

I'm not sure how I should generate a cert.pem file?

Answer (score 0):

If usage of `keytool` good for you please read this article
https://ultimatesecurity.pro/post/san-certificate/